# C# Same name of partial classes in web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have imported an old version of Web Forms Application code developed using old visual studio (not sure) developed by other team, but now I am using `visual studio 2012` and trying to import this project but getting lot of error, I have fixed few of them now stuck on this, please guys help me out on this.

Error I am getting:

> The type 'index' already contains a definition for 'strDescription'

For example I have created 2 files index.aspx and test.aspx in web forms like this (there are more than 50 files using the same partial class "index")

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="index" Codebehind="accepted-documents.aspx.cs" %>
```

index.cs and test.cs is generating lines somethings like this

```
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string strDescription, strKeyword;
}
```

I am new to .NET C# programming, please help me out this how do I resolve this issue in more than 50 files.

Comment: search for 'strDescription', check if its duplicate or not.

Comment: Yes it's included in every .cs files which is generated for .aspx file, partial class structure is somethings like this:

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string strDescription, strKeyword;
}

Comment: paste the partial code file here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have used the same variable name "strDescription" at the same level in more than one partial class. When the classes are compiled they are clubbed into a single class and hence the compiler might be seeing the same variable being declared twice.

Comment: Can you suggest me how do I resolve this issue in more than 50 .cs files?

Comment: You might have to rename the "strDescription" variable at one of the places and carefully rename/replace it. I do not see an easy way to change this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a member named strDescription in two different files that are part of the same class. Imagine the compiler taking all your partial classes an combining it into one class. . Then you'd end up with

public class index {
 public string strDescription;
 public string strDescription;
}

That is clearly invalid.

Why all the partial classes? I only use them when part of the class comes from a code generator. Unless you need them you can simplify your life by putting them all together in one file.

Comment: If I have develop this application I couldn't declare all the partial class with same variable names, but it's been developed by another team and now I am trying to import this project in visual studio but getting errors. Any idea how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you assume they gave you a working project? Put all partial classes back together in one class and it'll be easier to figure out the conflicts. This could never have compiled from what you've said here. Also try asking the other team

Comment: I'd get rid of the Hungarian notation too. . It's super clear it's a string in visual studio